# Is it the only case a reachable goto pointing to an unreachable label?

Tags: c#, unreachable-code

Inspired from question

- [What is a non-reachable end point(unreachable endpoint) of a statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168072/what-is-a-non-reachable-end-pointunreachable-endpoint-of-a-statement)

And before I ask this question, I've read:

- [C# Puzzle : Reachable goto pointing to an unreachable label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167666/c-sharp-puzzle-reachable-goto-pointing-to-an-unreachable-label)
- [Why does this "finally" execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141502/why-does-this-finally-execute/1141513)

The challenge in the question is

> write a program which has a reachable goto statement but the corresponding labelled statement is unreachable - Eric Lippert

and one feasible answer is like

```
    // the 3 lines are not important but declare variable for afterwards use
    var whateverException=new Exception("whatever exception");
    var whateverAction=default(Action);
    whateverAction=() => whateverAction();
```

```
    try {
        goto whateverLabel; // (1) the goto is reachable
    }
    finally {
        throw whateverException; // (3) because finally hijacks
    }

whateverLabel: // (2) but the label is not really reached
    whateverAction();
```

I'm wondering that in a single thread program, **is it the only case** a reachable goto pointing to an unreachable label? And is following code also considered a feasible answer of that?

```
here:
    int d=0, n=1/d;
    goto here;
```

Comment: A question without any vote, answer, or even a comment for four hours is really weird ..

Comment: The C# specification would consider your `goto here;` *reachable* because reachability only considers values of *constants*. `1/d` is not a constant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `finally`-blocked `goto` trick is in fact the only way to get a reachable goto that targets an unreachable label.

Comment: Thank you very much! No wonder this question hung for 7 hours!