# Help with Exception handlin in finally block

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch-finally

I am trying to catch an exception using a try-catch-finally block. i have caught the exception in the catch block and passed it to the finally block using a global exception variable. Doing so, i have handled the exception scenario in the finally block. I know this sounds wierd, but theres a need to do so. Please let me know if there is any coding standard issue with the same. Also if you can suggest something on the same, i will be really obliged.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the need? You could have just got rid of `catch` blog and had `finally` block.

Comment: you don't pass exceptions to finally blocks.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem you are trying to solve? There is most certainly a better way to solve it!

Answer (score 4):

`catch` is to catch the exception and do any necessary exception handling.  The `finally` block is there to clean up any left open resources, like file handles, database connections, etc.  This block will *most of the time* run and therefore is the correct place to do cleanup, but no the handle the exceptions themselves, those should be dealt with in the `catch` block.

Comment: Not _always_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141502/why-does-this-finally-execute/1141801#1141801

Answer (score 2):

The *try-catch-finally* pattern is a very useful and powerful pattern, if used as intended. Handling exceptions in the finally block is **not** recommended and does not make much (any?) sense.
Try to reorganize your code to fit the pattern, not the other way around.

Small example:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(path);
try
{
   // Do your work here
   reader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // Handle specific error here
    ShowUserError(ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle general error here
    LogError(ex);
}
finally
{
   // Perform clean up here
   // This code will run regardless if there was an error or not
   reader.Close();
}
```

Also, have a look at the MSDN documentation for [Try...Catch...Finally Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).